# Windows 10 doesn't support Nvidia Graphics. Any fix to this?

Tags: graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card, windows-10-preview

I downloaded the Windows 10 technical preview, and tried to run League of Legends. It wasn't running (gave an error message, something about DirectX), so I went to the NVIDIA control panel and made League run on integrated graphics. This worked, but now League is running VERY slowly. Is there a fix to this? (besides downgrading back to Windows 8.1)

Comment: Yeah; you wait for a driver to be released....you could try the 8.1 drivers but I do belive the windows display model was incremented

Comment: I simply re-installed the 8.1 driver, which worked fine.

Comment: Re-installing didn't work, one of the first things I tried

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about OS Alpha/Beta release issues and is of very limited lifetime. It will not help for future users, other than being an artifact of Microsoft's software testing program.

Comment: Apparently, this is only a problem with the Razer Blade 2014. All other laptops don't have any problems according to other users. There is no fix for this currently, guess the best thing is to wait until Razer comes out with an update.

Comment: the windows 10 support 352.86-desktop-win8-win7-winvista-32bit-international-whql version.............

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, this is only a problem with the Razer Blade 2014. All other laptops don't have any problems according to other users. There is no fix for this currently, guess the best thing is to wait until Razer comes out with an update.

Sources:

http://forum.notebookreview.com/razer/747532-razer-blade-2014-owner-s-lounge-179.html

https://forums.geforce.com/default/topic/779136/geforce-drivers/windows-10-technical-preview-display-driver-feedback-thread/

Comment: The hardware you are using might have been a useful thing to add in the original question.

Answer (score 6):

Technical previews are not designed for end users, it is for software designers (like the people who write those drivers). That way when Windows 10 has its general release drivers will be available day one.

The only solution is time. All you can do is wait for Nvidia to release a driver (keep a eye on their Beta drivers, it will be there first).

Comment: I understand that, but my question is is there a workaround to this, such as a registry tweak or something. Something like compatibility mode.

Comment: Drivers don't support compatability mode so they have to be supported and updated but that has to be updated

Comment: Take this for example: http://superuser.com/questions/821517/windows-10-technical-preview-synaptics-scrolling?noredirect=1#comment1098563_821517

Answer (score 0):

My fix is to install the latest nvidia driver 344.16 and create a batch file with the following.

> net stop nvsvc
>
> net start nvsvc

You will need to run it after every login.

Comment: Did it, but the Nvidia Driver still doesn't work. Here are the commands I put in: C:\WINDOWS\system32>net stop nvsvc
The NVIDIA Display Driver Service service is stopping.
The NVIDIA Display Driver Service service was stopped successfully.


C:\WINDOWS\system32>net start nvsvc
The NVIDIA Display Driver Service service is starting.
The NVIDIA Display Driver Service service was started successfully.